# "calling thread cannot access this object" exception when working with live visual tree in multithreaded UI WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have WPF app with two windows running on different threads (each window has its own thread). First window is basically a splash-screen, and second is main UI of my app.

When i use Live Visual Tree (selecting some element) or Live Property Explorer (searching properties) very often i will get "calling thread cannot access this object" exception. On some debugging sessions i will not get this exception at all.

My guess is that Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer somehow using one of my UI threads to get info they use. If they try and use thread of first window (splash-screen) to access visual elements created on second thread, i will get an exception.

Can somebody help me with this?

And please do not suggest using one thread for UI.

Edit:

I found out that most likely this exception occurs when i examine ui elements with some binding. That is - exception happens when Live Visual Tree or Live Property Explorer tries to access data context object, not just examine any property of ui element.

Comment: If you are competent enough to have create an application with multiple UI threads then you should understand why Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer will sometimes throw this exception; hint: They're using the "default" UI thread to try to access elements you have instantiated from a different thread.
I don't think you'll be able to change this behaviour so you may have to rethink you're architecture/debugging approach.

Comment: @ibebbs, as i stated in my question on some debugging sessions i will not get this exception. This means that sometimes Live Visual Tree will use correct UI thread (not "default"). So maybe there is some special way to use it (some hack). In any case, if my and your guess is right, and Live Visual Tree uses wrong UI thread, then it is another bug in visual studio.

Comment: Is it possible that in some sessions, the control's you're examining with the Live Visual Tree have been instantiated on the default UI thread and this is why you're not seeing the exceptions? Multiple UI threads is certainly not a 'normal' approach and it would surprise me if these tools were designed to support the scenario.

Comment: @ibebbs, no it is not possible. I understand that having multiple UI threads is not a common use case, nonetheless i would not say that it is not 'normal'. And i can assure you, if i could use one UI thread, i would not use several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem:

Somewhere in your application you need to subscribe to the following event:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException;
```

body of CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException can be something like this:

```
private void CurrentOnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        if (Debugger.IsAttached
            && (e.Exception?.InnerException?.StackTrace.Contains("System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()") ?? false)
            && (e.Exception?.InnerException?.StackTrace.Contains("Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.TypeServices.TypeService.GetProperties(Object target)") ?? false))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
        }
        else
            ShowExceptionMessage(e.Exception);
    }
```

ShowExceptionMessage is not important here, it can be any error handler you like, or you can even get rid of it (not that i recommend it).

Additionally you can check e.Exception?.InnerException?.Message. I did not included this check here, because message will be language specific.